# Multi-range query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to execute a single query for multiple, distinct ranges of documents in MongoDB?

e.g.

`!(x > 10 && x < 20) && !(x > 25 && x < 30)`, where `x` is some field.

Comment: How could `x` be less than 20 and greater than 25?

Comment: Actually, I meant to query for exclusions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can construct that query using `$or` with the `$gte` and `$lte` operators by inverting the boolean expression:

```js
db.coll.find({
    $or: [{x: {$lte: 10}}, {x: {$gte: 20, $lte: 25}}, {x: {$gte: 30}}]
})
```